# Adding loop variable output to a file in an Ansible playbook using a shell command

Tags: loops, variables, ansible

Trying to load a shell command as a variable so i can add the output to a file and use it against a loop.

What I need this to do is pass the loop value into the getent string as a variable, and then have it added to a file. The output of
`getent passwd {{item}} |sed -E 's/:[^ ]*:(.)[^ ]* ([^:]*).*/\L,\1\2/'`
should be
`user1,uone user2,utwo`

Here is what I have, but it dumps the wrong info into the file.

```
- hosts: all
  remote_user: root
  gather_facts: no
  tasks:

  - name: Add user variable
    ansible.builtin.shell: getent passwd {{item}} |sed -E 's/:[^ ]*:(.)[^ ]* ([^:]*).*/\L,\1\2/'
    register: getent_result
    ignore_errors: true
    loop:
     - user1
     - user2

  - name: Add user to file.txt
    ansible.builtin.lineinfile:
      path: "/path/to/file/file.txt"
      regexp: '^{{item}}'
      line: '{{getent_result}}'
      insertafter: 'EOF'
      create: yes
    loop:
     - user1
     - user2
```

What ends up in the file is this.

`{'msg': 'All items completed', 'changed': True, 'results': [{'stderr_lines': [], 'ansible_loop_var': 'item', 'end': '2023-05-18 13:30:53.434569', 'stderr': '', 'stdout': 'user1,uone', 'changed': True, 'rc': 0, 'start': '2023-05-18 13:30:53.420151', 'failed': False, 'cmd': "getent passwd user1 |sed -E 's/:[^ ]*:(.)[^ ]* ([^:]*).*/\\L,\\1\\2/'", 'item': 'user1', 'delta': '0:00:00.014418', 'invocation': {'module_args': {'creates': None, 'executable': None, '_uses_shell': True, 'strip_empty_ends': True, '_raw_params': "getent passwd user1 |sed -E 's/:[^ ]*:(.)[^ ]* ([^:]*).*/\\L,\\1\\2/'", 'removes': None, 'argv': None, 'warn': True, 'chdir': None, 'stdin_add_newline': True, 'stdin': None}}, 'stdout_lines': ['user1,uone'], 'ansible_facts': {'discovered_interpreter_python': '/usr/bin/python'}}, {'stderr_lines': [], 'ansible_loop_var': 'item', 'end': '2023-05-18 13:30:54.332020', 'stderr': '', 'stdout': 'user2,utwo', 'changed': True, 'rc': 0, 'failed': False, 'cmd': "getent passwd user2 |sed -E 's/:[^ ]*:(.)[^ ]* ([^:]*).*/\\L,\\1\\2/'", 'item': 'user2', 'delta': '0:00:00.011729', 'invocation': {'module_args': {'creates': None, 'executable': None, '_uses_shell': True, 'strip_empty_ends': True, '_raw_params': "getent passwd user2 |sed -E 's/:[^ ]*:(.)[^ ]* ([^:]*).*/\\L,\\1\\2/'", 'removes': None, 'argv': None, 'warn': True, 'chdir': None, 'stdin_add_newline': True, 'stdin': None}}, 'stdout_lines': ['user2,utwo'], 'start': '2023-05-18 13:30:54.320291'}]}`

instead of this

```
user1,uone
user2,utwo
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that you're writing the entire contents of `getent_result`. Instead, you want to extract the `stdout` from the results for each iteration of your loop.

```yaml
  - name: Add user to file.txt
    ansible.builtin.lineinfile:
      path: "/path/to/file/file.txt"
      regexp: "^{{ item.stdout | split(',') | first }}"
      line: "{{ item.stdout }}"
      insertafter: "EOF"
      create: yes
    loop: "{{ getent_result.results }}"
```

Answer (score 1):

Iterate *stdout* only

```yaml
    - lineinfile:
        path: /tmp/file.txt
        line: "{{ item }}"
        insertafter: EOF
        create: true
      loop: "{{ getent_result.results|map(attribute='stdout')|select }}"
```

Notes:

- The filter [*select*](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/latest/templates/#jinja-filters.select) is used to remove empty items.
- The parameter [*regexp*](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/lineinfile_module.html#parameter-regexp) is not needed if the whole *item* as is should be present in the file.
- The files will be created on the remote hosts.